# Communicating via Modbus RTU over TCP/IP Protocol

Tags: python, tcp, serial-port, communication, modbus

I'm trying to establish a connection with a device on my network and have 2 Modbus Protocol
related questions:

1. Is the protocol used by this controller "Modbus RTU over TCP" or "Modbus TCP"?

Here is the device manufacturer's description describing the connection:

"To read and write data, port 10001 is used as a TCP/IP tunnel. This means the MODBus
protocol is tunneled in RAW binaries through the XPort device. Only the MODBus
telegram is sent to the controller."

2. Depending on the protocol, how should the client request to read/write be formulated?

Assuming it's Modbus TCP I have written a simple code in Python to read a register by sending a Modbus request formated as shown bellow, I received no meaningful data.

[image: MODBUS TCP/IP]

Comment: *"Is the protocol used by this controller ...."* - nothing is known about the controller except what you cite. Typically Modbus TCP is used on port 502 though. Since here a different port is used this might point to Modbus RTU over TCP. *"Depending on the protocol, how should the client request to read/write be formulated?"* - what part of the specification is unclear to you in this regard? *"....  I received no meaningful data"* - it might be the wrong protocol or it might be a bug in your code or it might be the wrong FC+data. How should we know?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, the description I included is the only info provided regarding the protocol, that's why I wanted to make sure it is RTU over TCP.
In that case I'd like to know if the command I send should be (MBAP +PDU) or a different format, also Modbus CRC is not included in the TCP protocol, is it the case for RTU over TCP? That way I can determine if the problem is in the code or the format of the request.

Comment: Modbus RTU/IP is like Modbus TCP, only the 16 bit CRC added like in RTU and also included in the length.

Comment: It is not only the CRC bytes the difference, the byte sequence differs between Modbus TCP and RTU, and RTU also requires pause times that do not exist in TCP. You have to use a specific converter.

Answer (score 0):

Modbus RTU and Modbus TCP are two different protocols, the difference is not only the added CRC bytes.

The byte sequence is different, Modbus TCP include a transaction identifier, which allows sending several requests before receiving each response, if the connected slaves allow it.

Modbus RTU over TCP is not a standard protocol, I have never seen a device that uses such protocol.

If you want to connect to a Modbus RTU slave from a Modus TCP master you need a gateway converter between both protocols,  there are many different ones on the market.

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the protocol suggests that there is a distinct [xPort](https://www.lantronix.com/products/xport) TCP to serial converter in the communication path. This is further reinforced by the nonstandard port 10001 (MODBUS is usually TCP 502) common to converters of this type. In this case, the underlying MODBUS device will only be aware of the serial layer.

The communication should be MODBUS RTU across the TCP socket. The converter will then strip out the RTU message from the stream for the device.

**Note** the PDU formats are different between the two encapsulations. Silence is a typical response as the messages are never successfully parsed and so discarded.